# How To slider bar move when tap on the TableCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, slider, uislider

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    //frame for the slider
    CGRect myFrame = CGRectMake(60.0f, 10.0f, 250.0f, 25.0f);
    //create and initialize the slider
    mySlider = [[UISlider alloc] initWithFrame:myFrame];
    //set the minimum value
    self.mySlider.minimumValue = 0.0f;
    //set the maximum value
    self.mySlider.maximumValue = 100.0f;
    //set the initial value
    self.mySlider.value = 25.0f;

    //set this to true if you want the changes in the sliders value
    //to generate continuous update events
    [self.mySlider setContinuous:true];

    //attach action so that you can listen for changes in value
    [self.mySlider addTarget:self action:@selector(getSliderValue:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    //add the slider to the view
    [selectedView addSubview:self.mySlider];


    //move the origin for the Step Slider
    myFrame.origin.y += myFrame.size.height + 20.0f;
    self.myStepSlider = [[UISlider alloc] initWithFrame:myFrame];
    self.myStepSlider.minimumValue = 0.0f;
    self.myStepSlider.maximumValue = 100.0f;
    self.myStepSlider.value = 30.0f;
    [self.myStepSlider setContinuous:false];
    [self.myStepSlider addTarget:self action:@selector(getSliderValue:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    [selectedView addSubview:self.myStepSlider];

    [cell.containter addSubview:selectedView];
}

- (void) getSliderValue:(UISlider *)paramSender{

    //if this is my Step Slider then change the value
    if ([paramSender isEqual:self.myStepSlider]){
        float newValue = paramSender.value /10;
        paramSender.value = floor(newValue) * 10;
    }
    NSLog(@"Current value of slider is %f", paramSender.value);
}
```

Comment: only code? not one explanation?

Comment: @Daniele94 Does the title count?

Comment: @CrimsonChris no, it doesn't. technically, its not a question, because it doesnt contain the "?" character. its also not proper english grammar, and for me (a non-native-speaker) it's incomprehensible what he is asking.

Comment: @CrimsonChris: no indentation of the code. Not explanations for the problems. Only a request thrown. I dont like it sorry. I Unfortunately i cant give downvote on questions

Comment: @Daniele94 - please flag it as "unclear what you are asking". I did this already...

Comment: I was being sarcastic.

Answer (score 0):

Add the slider to your cell when creating it not in the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`:
Also explain your problem more thoroughly next time.